# remove class attribute from <a> tag wordpress

Tags: jquery

I am unable to remove the class tag from html page in wordpress.
I have tried

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
setTimeout(function() {
        $('#Deepak').removeAttr('Class1 Class2');
}, 250);
});
```

But it not working.

I tried the same with condition...

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    setTimeout(function() {
        var myAttr = $('#Deepak').attr('Class1 Class2');
        if (typeof myAttr !== 'undefined' && myAttr !== false) {
            $('#Deepak').removeAttr('Class1 Class2');
        }
    }, 250);
});
```

tried other approaches...

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#Deepak").removeAttr("class");       
});​
```

i am not been ableto figure out the problem.

HTML Script

```
<table>
        <tbody><tr><td>
        <a id="Deepak" onclick="showImage(this)" href="#http://localhost:8080/escproductcatalogue/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/cisco-catalyst-3750-x-series1.jpg" data-href="http://localhost:8080/escproductcatalogue/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/cisco-catalyst-3750-x-series1.jpg" class="Class1 Class2"> 
        <img src="http://localhost:8080/escproductcatalogue/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/cisco-catalyst-3750-x-series1.jpg"> 
        </a></td>
        <td>
        <a id="Deepak" onclick="showImage(this)" href="#http://localhost:8080/escproductcatalogue/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Cisco-Nexus-5000-Series.jpg" data-href="http://localhost:8080/escproductcatalogue/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Cisco-Nexus-5000-Series.jpg" class="Class1 Class2"> 
        <img src="http://localhost:8080/escproductcatalogue/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Cisco-Nexus-5000-Series.jpg"> 
        </a></td>
        </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Use `.removeClass` (https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

Comment: did u mean u have added custom attribute class1 class2?

Comment: your question is not clear, you want to remove class tag and you are trying for attribute?

Comment: just update my question..added the html..

Comment: @Newinjava..i am just trying to remove the class1 & class2, with remove class or removeAttr.
The purpose is same.

Comment: @humorousdragon i meant there is difference in "tag" and "attribute". Tags are used to mark up the start and end of an HTML element. An attribute defines a property for an element, consists of an attribute/value pair, and appears within the element's start tag.

Answer (score 2):

Your third code should work fine to remove whole class attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#Deepak").removeAttr("class");       
});​
```

Also if you want to remove some classes from your element you should try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Deepak").removeClass("class1 class2");       
});​
```

EDIT:

Here is the [JsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/aoc7hkmu/) which first alerts with the classes names and then alerts after removing the classes. It works!

EDIT 2:

If you want to use this for all occurrences. Then you should use class selector rather than id. Here is the example :

HTML should be like this:

```
<div class="Deepak class1 class2"></div>
<div class="Deepak class1 class3"></div>
<div class="Deepak class1 class4"></div>
```

Your code to remove all class attributes from all div's:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $(".Deepak").removeAttr("class");       
});​
```

And also if you need to remove specific classes from it you can do it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $(".Deepak").removeClass("class1 class2");       
});​
```

Comment: There is no closing bracket missing. It's in the last line.

Comment: you have added extra closing braces for second method

Comment: Yup i have removed it in this edit. anyways thanks @SteffenKreutz.

Comment: @RohitArora:     removeClass('') with or without class name..not having any effect

Comment: @humorousdragon I have added a jsfiddle , Check it . It should work. any errors in console ?

Comment: @RohitArora... U r a saviour...
Will that work for all the occureneces or do i need to create a loop?

Comment: @humorousdragon Check out my new Edit for all occurrences.

Comment: @RohitArora...i have already accepted your answer...But there is a difference between ready and load event...    
ready :- will wait till the document is loaded(DOM tree is loaded) and not till the entire window is loaded.    
load :- waits for the entire window to be loaded i.e. when all content (e.g. images) also has been loaded.  this was the main issue in my case...

Comment: @humorousdragon Ok no probz.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Rohit Arora & Newinjava...
with your help i been able to do this..

```
 $(window).bind("load", function() {
alert( $('#Deepak').attr('class'));
 $('#Deepak').removeAttr('class');
 alert( $('#Deepak').attr('class'));
});
```

The classes need to removed after the whole page has been loaded...so this piece of code worked for me.. :)

Comment: @AnirudhSharma...the issue here was that in my case the classes are generating dynamically, that is the reason i am removing them using script.
although i have used the same codes before asking the question...what solved my problem was that i needed to run the code after page load event...
look at the codes that i have tried and were included in the question too...

Answer (score 1):

You probably need [`removeClass`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) instead of `removeAttr`, as you wont have any attribute with name `Class1`

```
 $('#Deepak').removeClass('Class1 Class2');
```

If you want to remove all classes you pass no parameter

```
 $('#Deepak').removeClass();
```

If you want to remove attribute from element you can use removeAttr

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/km3pwf41/)**

```
alert( $('#Deepak').attr('class'));
 $('#Deepak').removeAttr('class');
alert( $('#Deepak').attr('class'));
```

Comment: I think OP needs to remove class attribute not particular classes.

Comment: @RohitArora...i want to remove the class attribute..or all the classes...
    .removeClass('') with or without class name..not having any effect..

Comment: @Adil..thanks for the "ALERT"...didnt thought of using that in first place.</br> When i tried this it said undefined in both the messages..so now i m thinking that when is the class is being added to the page...</br>I have added 250 delay in of the codes, just to be sure for the same, but it was of no use...

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us your HTML? Because without the HTML we are unable to tell for certain if this code will work.
Your third code snippet should work as Rohit already pointed out, allthough i dont think he missed a bracket.
But it all depends on the HTML, make sure there is an element with the id Deepak and that is actually has an attribute class and the css class you are trying to remove.
If that is all correct add a simple alert as your first line in the document.ready just to check your code is being executed.
Maybe you are missing the reference to the jquery lib?
I always you Firebug, but any other browser dev tool will work, to step through my jquery code.

Comment: adding coommet would be better?This is not answer

Comment: @SomnathKharat He cannot add it , His reputation is not much to add comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#yourid").removeClass();//Calling removeClass with no parameters will remove all of the item's classes.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/au80zap8/

Comment: I have already tried the same with <div> tag and it was working, but it is not working with my current html /<a> tag.
i am not been able to figure out the reason of the same not working with this code..
although i did tried the same again..nd no result.

Comment: @humorousdragon i copied your anchor tag and tried , and it worked. http://jsfiddle.net/au80zap8/2/

Comment: try to debug your code, check if it is executing that line which is used to remove class. Or else update your code in jsfiddle and give us the link.